# awk regex compile failed

Tags: linux, bash, awk

trying to do a regex replacement with a lookahead (thus `awk` and not `sed`) that removes all dots save the last one to preserve the extension `eg: (my.big.file.avi > my-big-file.avi)`.  here's my little bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar nullglob dotglob
for file in ./**/*.{mpg,mpeg,mkv,avi,mp4}; do
        newFile=$(printf $file | awk '{gsub(/\.(?=.*?\.)/"-");}1')
        #ffmpeg -i "$newFile" -vcodec copy -acodec aac "${newFile%.*}_AAC.mp4"
        printf "${file} ---> ${newFile}\n"
done
```

this gives me a `regular expression compile failed (missing operand)` error...

i can't see it.  can someone point me to my mistake?

Comment: `?=` is PCRE syntax. It isn't available in BRE or ERE, and so isn't available in awk. Same for `*?`. Read the fine manual for your awk implementation to determine exactly which regex syntax extensions it honors.

Comment: I think you mean PERE and ERE

Comment: BTW, there are _very_ good reasons not to use PCRE -- perl's regular expressions are many, many orders of magnitude slower than the traditional ones that 1970s-era versions of awk use. See https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html for a classic paper (by one of the original UNIX authors) on the topic.

Comment: Also, `printf $file` is buggy. If you want to emit the filename exactly as it's written, `printf '%s\n' "$file"` is more likely to be what you want (or you can use `<<<"$file"`, which is often faster.

Comment: works as consititued in Perl, Python, Javascript, PHP, and GoLang but NOT bash!??!? ok, fine, be that as it may, what is the solution?

Comment: @WhiteRau, I told you the solution above -- rewrite your regex to use only ERE syntax. Python, Javascript, etc. got their regex extensions from Perl; whereas awk (which is not part of bash but a separate language) is older than perl.

Comment: (also, `printf %s ---> %s\n' "$file" "$newFile"`)

Comment: @WhiteRau, ...btw, golang's regexes are an interesting data point in the discussion - the implementation is written by the same person as the paper above, and they deliberately avoid the most problematic parts of PCRE. The Python `re2` library is likewise of a new generation that avoids PCRE's problems.

Comment: sorry.  misread that as ERE wasn't supported... not that that means anything to me at this point, but i'll read on and learn!  :)  thanks.  i was using `regex101.com` to build test the expressions and then in bash.  didn't think i'd have compatibility issues this way... happy to learn something new, even though there was no solution given.

Comment: I've extended my answer to show using bash native (ERE) regular expressions (as opposed to awk ones)

Comment: ...see that code running in an online sandbox (modified to not need files to actually exist on disk) at https://ideone.com/11F3rL

Comment: The error you obtain is because you miss a comma after your first ERE. The fact that you try to use PCRE syntax within `gsub` is not the cause of the error, however it will not work as you expect.  This wil not throw an error but will still not work as you want: `awk '{gsub(/\.(?=.*?\.)/,"-");}1'`

Comment: @kvantour yep.  the comma was missing.  but, like >CharlesDuffy said, ERE doesn't support lookarounds, so this doesn't do the job in bash.  the regex works flawlessly everywhere else though... dang it.  :D

Comment: @CharlesDuffy good lord, that paper is dense! not to impose, but can you distill WHY they don't use lookarounds anymore?  more for my instant gratification of curiosity...  :D

Comment: The real problem is backtracking, and its ability to cause unbounded time complexity -- re2 (as used by Go and available as a Python module) has added support for more (but not all) PCRE features _without_ needing to backtrack, but for a long time your options were either PCRE-that-could-backtrack (and thus be incredibly, unreasonably slow with inputs that exercised worse-case behavior of a given regex), or traditional-re-that-couldn't (and didn't offer newer features).

Comment: I've seen some efforts to build command line tools with re2-based implementations, but they're not widespread yet, and certainly not POSIX-standardized; falls into the category of "these things are slow, and changing standards takes time".

Comment: If you want to rename using `perl`-style regular expression take look at https://www.howtogeek.com/423214/how-to-use-the-rename-command-on-linux/

Answer (score 4):

You don't need awk, or regular expressions, for any part of solving this problem; [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) suffices.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar nullglob dotglob
for file in ./**/*.{mpg,mpeg,mkv,avi,mp4}; do
        dirname=${file%/*}    # we don't want to change the directory name
        filename=${file##*/}  # so split out just the filename
        [[ $filename = *.*.* ]] || continue  # no compound extension? do nothing
        file_start=${filename%.*}  # content up to last dot
        file_ext=${filename##*.}   # content after last dot
        newFile=${dirname}/${file_start//./-}.${file_ext} # combine the two
        # okay, got what we need, now we can work with it
        #ffmpeg -i "$newFile" -vcodec copy -acodec aac "${newFile%.*}_AAC.mp4"
        printf '%s ---> %s\n' "$file" "$newFile"
done
```

But if you *want* to use regular expressions:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar nullglob dotglob
for file in ./**/*.{mpg,mpeg,mkv,avi,mp4}; do
    [[ $file =~ ^(.*)/([^/]+)[.]([^/.]+)$ ]] || continue
    dirname=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    file_start=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    file_ext=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
    newFile=${dirname}/${file_start//./-}.${file_ext}
    printf '%s ---> %s\n' "$file" "$newFile"
done
```

Comment: okay.  today is Unlearn Everything Day...  i've been using the RegEx style as showed forever in other dev environments, but apparently the bash scripting world is another forking galaxy that does not connect!  O_o  no matter.  thank you for the rework.  i now know what i'll be doing for the rest of the day/week/month.  ;)  all this just to remove some damn dots!  :P

Comment: i looked at your sandbox code.  the problem is that it removes the dotted elements and i need to keep them:  this.file.name.must.remain.txt --> this-file-name-must-remain.txt

Comment: Sorry 'bout that, I misunderstood the question. See edits.

Answer (score 0):

GNU `AWK` has limited supported for lookaheads, namely `$` for end of line and `\>` for end of word. Your task, namely

> removes all dots save the last one to preserve the extension eg:
> `(my.big.file.avi > my-big-file.avi)`

might be accomplished using GNU `AWK`'s functions for working with strings, I would do it as follows, let `file.txt` content be

```
my.big.file.avi
i-do-not-need-change.mp3
name-without-dot
```

then

```
awk '{match($0,/[.][^.]*$/); print gensub(/[.]/,"-","g",substr($0,1,RSTART-1)) substr($0,RSTART)}' file.txt
```

output

```
my-big-file.avi
i-do-not-need-change.mp3
name-without-dot
```

Note: I added 2 test cases. Explanation: Firstly use `match` to look for literal dot (`[.]`) followed by zero or more (`*`) not-dots (`[^.]`) and followed by end of line (`$`). This will set `RSTART` to position of last dot in line. Then I use `substr` to get part before last dot and part with last dot and following character. In 1st part I replace all dots with -, in 2nd I do nothing, then concatenate them and `print`. If you want to know more about functions I used read [String Functions docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html).

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Keep in mind some file have 2 dots in extension, for example `file.tar.gz`, my solution does not that into account.

> (thus `awk` and not `sed`)

**Scary warning**: `sed` is [Turing complete](https://catonmat.net/proof-that-sed-is-turing-complete). Ramifcation: it can do anything other Turing language can accomplish. That being said that it can does mean you should use it.

Answer (score 0):

2 verbose approaches in awk :

```
  [m/g/n]awk 'BEGIN { OFS =  "-"
                       FS = "[.]"
        } ($NF="."$NF) \
                     && \ 
                sub(/\-\./,".")'
```

...versus...

```
  [m/g/n]awk 'sub(/\.[^.]+$/,"\0&") + \
              gsub(/\./,    "-")     + \
              sub(/\0\-/, ".")    + 1'
```

I chose \0 because the null byte isn't valid in files inside just about any file system, which makes it a safe choice for using as a temporary anchor (even better than awk SUBSEP, which isn't illegal in POSIX filesystems)

Answer (score -1):

And an alternative nowhere near as elegant as Charles', but maybe also does the job ...

```
echo my.big.file.avi | sed -E 's/\./-/g;s/-([^-]+)$/.\1/'
my-big-file.avi
```